# Unable to post message to my facebook using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook

```
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user. thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\fyp\plugin\facebook-sdk\src\base_facebook.php on line 1106
```

The problem is like mentioned above. I have spend sometime on searching the solution but that still not work after i modified the code. I notice this there is website to get one

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
    type=user_agent&
    client_id=116122545078207&
    redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fxyz.com&
    scope=user_photos,email,user_birthday,user_online_presence
```

Can i include it into my script? so that i don't have to going this url everytime

.And how to include it into my phpscript so that the problem can be fixed?

Thank you for any kind of help.

```
<?require 'plugin/facebook-sdk/src/facebook.php';

$session='123456';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => '1234567',
  'secret' => '123456789',
  'cookie' => true,
));

$me = null;
// Session based API call.
if ($session) {
  try {
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    $me = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
  }
}


// login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
if ($me) {
  $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
} else {
  $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
}


if ($session) {
    // We have a valid FB session, so we can use 'me'
 $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed','post',array('message' => 'testmessage'));
} elseif( isset($_SESSION['user_id']) ) {
$result = $facebook->api("/{$_SESSION['user_id']}/feed",'post',array('message' => 'testmessage'));
}
?>
```

Comment: I am bit confuse about that , that token is generate once i  login ?

Comment: $facebook->setAccessToken($new_access_token);
I can use this to set the token but how can i get it?
Also, it seems there are some setting to not to change the token
 thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit Scope ,

```
scope=user_photos,email,user_birthday,user_online_presence,publish_stream
```

& visit this link again

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?
    type=user_agent&
    client_id=116122545078207&
    redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fxyz.com&
    scope=user_photos,email,user_birthday,user_online_presence,publish_stream
```

Comment: i have to include offline access in it?

Comment: actually i am the owner of the facebook page and it is quite weird to obtain an access token before i can post something to my page? I know it is design for application use but is there any more direct way to post the message onto my own board? thank you

Comment: well, if you want to post to page as page 
first yo should get page access_token 
from me/accounts